# Efficient output data structure in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, stl

I am working on the Interval Partitioning problem (eg: http://kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/interval-partitioning-problem/) where I have to write the optimal schedules to an output file. I am currently using a map> to store the intervals assigned to several partitions. The first int denoted the partition number and the vector corresponding to it denotes the intervals assigned to that partition.

To write the contents out to a file, I am iterating through all the keys of the map and writing out the vector for each key. Is this the most efficient data structure to store the data (partition_number,intervals) ? or Can I use something other than a map so that I can write the output in a much faster way ?

Comment: The data structure in the file doesn't have to match the data structure in memory.  For example, the data structure in the data file wants to be designed for ease of readability and fast parsing / processing.  The data file may also contain fields for integrity support.

Comment: How often are you writing to the file?  How often are you reading from it?  Is the data large or small?

Comment: BTW, pointers to objects in memory do not translate to data files, because your program may not be located in the same location or your memory may not be at the same location from one invocation to another.

Comment: Is there a time constraint for writing to the file?  For reading from the file?

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends upon what you are trying to output. For example, a better data structure for solving this problem is a `std::forward_list<std::pair<int,int>>` where the first `int` would be the time and the second `int` would be the number of currently required partitions.

Given the requests:

[image]

Your `std::forward_list` would contain the `std::pair`s:

(time, partitions)
{0, 1},
{1, 2},
{3, 3},
{4, 1},
{5, 2},
{6, 1},
{7, 0}

Bear in mind that when you're working with file IO, the IO is going to be the lion share of the cost. So at this point it's simply a question of how much effort do you want to put into dumping that data. If printing the essentials like this isn't enough let me know and I can probably hook something else up:

```
std::cout << "(time, partitions)" << std::endl;
for(auto i = partitions.begin(); i != partitions.end(); ++i){
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << i->first << std::setw(1) << ',' << std::setw(12) << i->second << std::endl;
}
```